# Identifier 'title' is not defined. '__object' does not contain such a member

Tags: angular, angularfire2

In my slow quest of understanding Angular etc I have an error from my visual studio code editor that does not seem to affect the application functions.

when I hover over a variable in the Html template I receive this popup

[image]

My html template is riddle with errors for everything related to the product object product.ETC...

Could someone point me in the right direction in understanding how to decipher this.

product-form.component.html

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-6">
      <form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(form.value)">

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="title">Title</label>
              <input #title="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="product.title" name="title" id="title" type="text" class="form-control" required>
              <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="title.touched && title.invalid">
                Title is required.
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="price">Price</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input #price="ngModel" ngModel [(ngModel)]="product.price" name="price" id="price" type="number" class="form-control" required [min]="0">
                </div>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="price.touched && price.invalid">
                  <div *ngIf="price.errors.required">Price is required.</div>
                  <div *ngIf="price.errors.min">Price should be 0 or higher.</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="category">Category</label>
                <select #category="ngModel" ngModel [(ngModel)]="product.category" name="category" id="category" class="form-control" required>
                  <option value=""></option>
                  <option *ngFor="let category of categories$ | async" [value]="category.key">{{ category.payload.val().name }}</option>
                </select>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="category.touched && category.invalid">
                  Category is required.
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="imageUrl">Image URL</label>
                <input #imageUrl="ngModel" ngModel [(ngModel)]="product.imageUrl" name="imageUrl" id="imageUrl" type="text" class="form-control" required url>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="imageUrl.touched && imageUrl.invalid">
                  <div *ngIf="imageUrl.errors.required">Image URL is required.</div>
                  <div *ngIf="imageUrl.errors.url">Please enter a valid URL.</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>

          </form>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
          <img class="card-img-top" [src]="product.imageUrl" *ngIf="product.imageUrl">
          <div class="card-block">
            <h4 class="card-title">{{ product.title }}</h4>
            <p class="card-text">{{ product.price | currency: 'USD': symbol }}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

product-form.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CategoryService } from '../../category.service';
import { ProductService } from '../../product.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-form',
  templateUrl: './product-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-form.component.css']
})
export class ProductFormComponent implements OnInit {

  categories$;
  product = {};

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private categoryService: CategoryService,
    private productService: ProductService) {
    this.categories$ = categoryService.getCategories();

    let id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    if (id) {
      this.productService.get(id).take(1).subscribe(p => this.product = p);
    }
  }

  save(product) {
    this.productService.create(product);
    this.router.navigate(['/admin/products']);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

product.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Injectable()
export class ProductService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  create(product) {
    this.db.list('/products').push(product);
  }

  getAll() {
    return this.db.list('/products').snapshotChanges();
  }

  get(productId) {
    return this.db.object('/products/' + productId).valueChanges();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You define the variable product as an Object

```
product = {};
```

The object itself does not have any members, so the warning is shown to signal this. This does not cause any issues, because the compiled javascript does not care. This is purely a Typescript "error".

You have two options:

1. You declare the product variable with any `product: any = {};`
2. You create an interface/type/class for the pproduct with all the members an declare the variable of that type e.g. `product: Product = {};`

Comment: I do not fully understand interfaces at the moment so I have declared the product to any.

Answer (score 2):

What does it shows when you log the product object in console?.
 If it shows the data in it you can try this:

```
product['title'].
```

Hope it works!!